# sed with variable \n complication

Tags: bash, variables, sed, escaping

I am appending the content of a variable to a line. Seeing this odd result. Can you explain why a lowercase n in the content is being treated like a new line... suggest an alternate method?

```
# CLNAM='NED2k'; echo 'order code is ' | sed "s/$/\\$CLNAM/";
order code is NED2k

# CLNAM='Ned2k'; echo 'order code is ' | sed "s/$/\\$CLNAM/";
order code is Ned2k

# CLNAM='ned2k'; echo 'order code is ' | sed "s/$/\\$CLNAM/";
order code is

ed2k
```

The first two examples work giving a one line result as desired; the third example results in 2 lines with missing letter 'n' - something's interpreting it as a line break.

The above is simplified to illustrate the problem only. I am not using echo, so it's not as simple as just inserting the variable right in the echo command ;) 
My code is a loop through a list of subdomains; determine the nameserver to use then look up the A record and append the nameserver to that result.

```
do dig @$NSTU $SUBD A |grep "^$SUBD.*IN.*A"| sed "s/$/\\$NSTU/"
```

The expected result is AOK when the NS are in caps, but those that aren't end up splitting onto 2 lines and dropping that initial "n"

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in your command?

Comment: Oooops. Correct - it works without the backslashes!  I can't explain .. other than I tried many methods with awk sed echo and quotes, double quotes, etc; got mixed up. Thank you. Should I just delete this whole question?

Comment: Well, the question *can* be answered, and you (or someone else) might learn something, but it’s kind of marginal since it’s based on a stray character you didn’t really mean to include anyway.  Up to you (and any curiosity you have about the observed behavior).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your why question, when you do:

```
sed "s/$/\\$CLNAM/"
```

with `CLNAME=ned2k`

The expanded version of the command looks like:

```
sed "s/$/\ned2k/"
```

which means "for the end of the line, substitute a newline and `ed2k`".

The reason for this is that you escaped the second backslash by including the first one. Neither was needed. Perhaps you wanted to escape the dollar sign, but that's not necessary for two reasons:

1. The variable is evaluated inside double quotes before the result is passed to `sed` which, as a result, never sees the dollar sign
2. On the right side of a `sed` substitute function, dollar signs are literal (had the previous rule not taken place first, for example if there were single quotes instead of double)

Answer (score 0):

AWK supports passing variables which can get you out of quoting hell:

```
dig @$NSTU $SUBD A |awk -v re="^$SUBD.*IN.*A" -v n="$NSTU" '$0~re {print $0, n}'
```